# Routing Apple TV to hotel wifi using Internet Sharing on Macbook Pro -- something's wrong

Tags: networking, macos, mac, routing

Here's the idea:

"AppleTV" --ethernet-- --Thunderbolt ethernet adapter-- "Macbook Pro" --wifi adapter-- "Hotel wifi service"

I have the wifi service working properly on the macbook (it requires a browser login that the apple tv can't handle, hence all this effort)

I have the Thunderbolt Ethernet Connection set up as follows:

```
Configure IPv4: Manually
IP Address: 192.168.2.10
Subnet: 255.255.255.0
Router: (empty)
```

I have the AppleTV's network set up as follows:

```
Configure IPv4: Manually
IP Address: 192.168.2.20
Subnet: 255.255.255.0
Router: 192.168.2.10
DNS: 192.168.2.10
```

I have Internet Sharing turned on,

```
"Share your connection from:" Wi-Fi
"To computers using:" Thunderbolt Ethernet
```

Here's my "netstat -rn"

```
Routing tables

Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Refs      Use   Netif Expire
default            10.64.0.1          UGSc          367        0     en0
default            link#12            UCSI            2        0 bridge1
10.64/21           link#4             UCS             2        0     en0
10.64.0.1/32       link#4             UCS             3        0     en0
10.64.0.1          10:c:42:43:69:5d   UHLWIir       261      825     en0    486
10.64.0.28/32      link#4             UCS             1        0     en0
10.64.7.255        link#4             UHLWbI          1       71     en0
127                127.0.0.1          UCS             1        0     lo0
127.0.0.1          127.0.0.1          UH              4      154     lo0
169.254            link#4             UCS             1        0     en0
192.168.2.20       c8.69.cd.3a.82.c6  UHLWIi          2        0 bridge1   1200
255.255.255.255/32 link#4             UCS             2        0     en0
255.255.255.255    link#4             UHLWbI          1       59     en0

Internet6:
Destination                             Gateway                         Flags         Netif Expire
::1                                     ::1                             UHL             lo0
fdae:4181:f045:6a85::/64                fe80::7d95:ef0:2807:c43e%utun0  Uc            utun0
fdae:4181:f045:6a85:7d95:ef0:2807:c43e  link#11                         UHL             lo0
fe80::%lo0/64                           fe80::1%lo0                     UcI             lo0
fe80::1%lo0                             link#1                          UHLI            lo0
fe80::%en0/64                           link#4                          UCI             en0
fe80::7a31:c1ff:feb7:f504%en0           78:31:c1:b7:f5:4                UHLI            lo0
fe80::%awdl0/64                         link#8                          UCI           awdl0
fe80::4814:d4ff:fe4c:d1af%awdl0         4a:14:d4:4c:d1:af               UHLI            lo0
fe80::%en4/64                           link#9                          UCI             en4
fe80::6a5b:35ff:fea7:8fcc%en4           68:5b:35:a7:8f:cc               UHLI            lo0
fe80::%utun0/64                         fe80::7d95:ef0:2807:c43e%utun0  UcI           utun0
fe80::7d95:ef0:2807:c43e%utun0          link#11                         UHLI            lo0
fe80::%bridge100/64                     link#12                         UCI        bridge10
fe80::7831:c1ff:fe7b:5b64%bridge100     7a.31.c1.7b.5b.64               UHLI            lo0
ff01::%lo0/32                           ::1                             UmCI            lo0
ff01::%en0/32                           link#4                          UmCI            en0
ff01::%awdl0/32                         link#8                          UmCI          awdl0
ff01::%en4/32                           link#9                          UmCI            en4
ff01::%utun0/32                         fe80::7d95:ef0:2807:c43e%utun0  UmCI          utun0
ff01::%bridge100/32                     link#12                         UmCI       bridge10
ff02::%lo0/32                           ::1                             UmCI            lo0
ff02::%en0/32                           link#4                          UmCI            en0
ff02::%awdl0/32                         link#8                          UmCI          awdl0
ff02::%en4/32                           link#9                          UmCI            en4
ff02::%utun0/32                         fe80::7d95:ef0:2807:c43e%utun0  UmCI          utun0
ff02::%bridge100/32                     link#12                         UmCI       bridge10
```

...I'm thinking this should work. But it doesn't. Does anybody understand the netstat output? It's kind of greek to me.

Comment: Your Apple TV is on a different subnet than the hotel Wi-Fi. The hotel network has no idea how to reach that subnet. Your MacBook Pro would need to be set up to do NAT routing for that to work correctly.

Comment: Ok. How? I thought that's what Internet Connection Sharing *did*...

Comment: @RonMaupin OS X Internet Sharing *is* NAT.

Comment: You don't normally statically set addresses, etc. with NAT routing. All the examples of OSX NAT routing I have seen don't manually configure the interfaces.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that too; setting the ethernet up on both sides as "Automatic." Also didn't work.

Comment: Can you provide the output of "ifconfig"? I want to make sure you didn't add your Wi-Fi interface to the bridge.

Answer (score 1):

For detail explanation of a command usage on GNU/Linux or MAC OS X use the man command to get the command manual pages:

- `man netstat`

The netstat documentation should help you decipher the command's output.  Here is a link to the netstat online man page: [Mac OS X Netstat Command Man Page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/netstat.1.html)

To get you started - here is what I see (IPv4) that are typical netstat -r outputs for MAC OS X:

`default            10.64.0.1          UGSc          367        0     en0`

This is your default gateway that is status usable route and was manually created /configured through your networking software

`10.64/21           link#4             UCS             2        0     en0`

This is a link that is created by your network software to aid in routing/ "linking" to your default gateway - Usable route.

`10.64.0.1          10:c:42:43:69:5d   UHLWIir       261      825     en0    486`

This is more details on your gateway route. Noticed that it is attached to a MAC address (interface en0) and is status a default router.

`127.0.0.1          127.0.0.1          UH              4      154     lo0`

This is a local host route linked to local interface lo0.

`169.254            link#4             UCS             1        0     en0`

This looks like setup for link-local routing (Automatic Private IP Addressing (APIPA) addresses)

`10.64.0.28/32      link#4             UCS             1        0     en0`

Looks like a route setup to link back to default gateway network on interface en0.

`192.168.2.20       c8.69.cd.3a.82.c6  UHLWIi          2        0 bridge1   1200`

Looks like you manually configured this interface to act as a bridge attached to MAC and static IP address shown.

`If you are authorized to modify this network I would suggest that you need a route added to connect your "Internet" default gateway (IP Address: 10.64.0.1) and your newly created network - so your host (IP Address: 192.168.2.20) can communicate outside its local network.`

Please let us know how this works out for you.

Good luck!

Comment: As you said, the IP Address 192.168.2.20 needs to communicate outside its local network. In my OP I stated this: the AppleTV is 192.168.2.20 and I'm trying to connect it to my hotel's wifi.

    `default            link#12            UCSI            2        0 bridge1`

... What is this line doing?

Answer (score -1):

Looks like I was doing everything right. Turns out the hotel's wifi is inspecting MAC addresses. Since my Macbook Pro's MAC ID is the one that is registered/logged in to the hotel wifi, it (and only it) is able to access the internet. Any device it shares its connection with, however, is getting blocked.

Weak.

Comment: This is why many NAT implementations support MAC spoofing.

Comment: @JamieHanrahan They don't use MAC spoofing, they use the device's real MAC. It can't work any other way if you get your Internet from a WiFi client connection. This is normal router behavior and not any kind of spoofing.

Comment: The MAC address will be the address of the computer. This is how Internet Sharing works.

Comment: If you connect your "internet from a wifi client connection" to the "wan" side of a router, then connect several computers to the "lan" side, which computer's MAC address does the router present to the WAN side? It has to be just one (since it's a layer 3 device). By default it is the router's own MAC address. "MAC spoofing" lets you use one of your computer's MACs instead (presumably one previously registered with your ISP) - or some other that you specify. All the packets for all of your computers come back to your router and it sorts them out by port number in the usual way.